# Как привязать имя к изображению в laravel faker?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть ли возможность в laravel faker привязать имя к изображению ? например если в базе данных будет определенное имя то в другую колонку к нему будет записано выбранное изображение. По умолчанию все ставится рандомно.

```
public function definition() {
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->randomElement([
            'Summer Dress',   // Выбранное имя
            'Shoulder Bag', 
            'Warm Hat', 
            'Black Sneakers', 
            'Summer Pants', 
            'T-Shirt', 'Hand Bag'
         ]),
        'image' => $this->faker->randomElement([
            'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bk1o8dt9rztsvj1/img.png?dl=1',   // Выбранное изображение
            'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hdyula548tcjfwi/img.png?dl=2',
            'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bk1o8dt9rztsvj1/img.png?dl=3',
            'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bk1o8dt9rztsvj1/img.png?dl=4',
            'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bk1o8dt9rztsvj1/img.png?dl=5',
            'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bk1o8dt9rztsvj1/img.png?dl=6',
        ]),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Так вы сами и ответили на Ваш вопрос... У Вас имя и так привязывается к изображению... Конечно, Вы не сможете загрузить .png в БД, поэтому довольствуйтесь URLом

Comment: Я проверял, они не соответствуют друг другу в базе данных, тоесть список совсем другой чем тот который в коде. Имена не соответствуют изображению.

Comment: Можете скинуть URL картинки и URL в БД?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду показать ?

Comment: В смысле показать? Просто скиньте то, что у Вас в таблице базы данных

Comment: В таблице под номером 1 идет имя "Summer Dress" которое находиться первым по списку в коде, к нему применяется изображение ниже по списку которое не соответствует первым.

Comment: И в чём проблема? У Вас же прописано `randomElement`

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы имя которое идет первым по списку соответствовало изображению которое идет первым по списку. Или randomElement здесь совсем не подходить и нужно использовать что-то другое ?

Comment: Конечно не подходит... Я мало работал с так называемыми фабриками, но randomElement - с английского переводится рандомный элемент... То есть все элементы в списке рандомизируются

Comment: Понял, спасибо в любом случае.